# Merge dictionaries in different lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to merge two lists with dictionaries in them:

```
dict1 = [{'Count': '307', 'name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '7.7%'}, {'Count': '7,813', 'name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '6.8%'}...]
dict2 = [{'Place': 'Home'}, {'Place':'Forest'},...]
```

There are 56 elements in the first list (56 dictionaries) and 14 elements in the second list (dict2). What I want to do is inset first element from dict2 to first four elements of dict 1 and repeat the process until all 56 elements in dict1 have {Place:x}.

So eventually what I want to get is:

`newdict = [{'Count': '307', 'name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '7.7%', 'Place': 'Home'}, {'Count': '7,813', 'name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '6.8%', 'Place':'Home'},{'Name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '6.6%', 'Place': 'Home', 'Count': '1,960'},{'Name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '7.6%', 'Place': 'Home', 'Count': '1,090'},{'Name': 'Other', 'Percentage': '7.6%', 'Place': 'Forest', 'Count': '1,090'} ]`

and so on..

When `dict2` is exhausted, it should start from first element again.

**So I updated question. My first take on this problem was to increase number of same key:values in dict2 to:
     `dict2 = [{'Place': 'Home'}, {'Place':'Home'},{'Place':'Home'},{'Place':'Home'},{'Place':'Forest'},{'Place':'Forest'}...]`
and then use the same method mentioned below to merge dictionaries. But I believe there should be a way to do this without changing dict2.**

Comment: What should happen for the fifteenth element of the first list, after the second list is exhausted?

Comment: Your `dict2` has only 14 elements, what should happen when we process element 15 in `dict1?

Comment: It should start from first element again (of dict2).

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: `dict1` and `dict2` are not good names for `list`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll use `zip` and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to pair up elements from the two lists.

```
from itertools import cycle

for a, b in zip(dict1, cycle(dict2)):
    a.update(b)
```

If you don't want to modify the original list, it's a little more complex.

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

new_list = [{k:v for k, v in chain(a.items(), b.items())} for a, b in zip(dict1, cycle(dict2))]
```

Comment: This alters the originally given dictionaries, I don't know if this is the wanted behavior. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: If you want to build a new list... `[dict(a,**b) for a, b in zip(dict1, cycle(dict2))]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands even better!  I tried `dict(**a, **b)`, but that didn't work on the version of python i'm using so i gave up in favor of itertools

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  could you explain how second script works ? I don't understand what k:v for k, v in chain.from_iterable([a.items(), b.items()])} does ? It worked perfectly, but I just don't understand how.

Comment: @Extria Sure. It's  a dictionary comprehension, which is a way of building dictionaries from existing data. `items` is a method of dictionaries that returns the key, value pairs as a list of tuples.  [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) takes an iterable of subiterables (here a list of lists) and yields all the elements of the first subiterable, then all the elements of the second subiterable.  Basically, what we're doing here is making a new dictionary by putting together the two dictionaries we already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
res = []

for i, j in zip(dict1, dict2):
    res.append(i)
    res[-1].update(j)
```

If the number of items in your dicts are not the same, you can use [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with `fillvalue` param set to `{}`:

```
res = []

for i, j in itertools.izip_longest(dict1, dict2, fillvalue={}):
    res.append(i)
    res[-1].update(j)
```

Comment: how about a list comprehension: `[dict(x,**y) for x,y in zip(dict1,dict2)]`

Comment: @Chris_Rands That's a great option!

Answer (score 0):

Using modulo:

```
new_list = []
x = len(dict2)
for v, item in enumerate(dict1):
    z = item.copy()
    z['Place'] = dict2[v % x]['Place']
    new_list.append(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply creating an empty dictionary called `result` and simply updating it with the list of existing dictionaries you want merged, for example:

```
def merge_dicts(*dict_args):
    """
    Given any number of dicts, shallow copy and merge into a new dict,
    precedence goes to key value pairs in latter dicts.
    :param dict_args: a list of dictionaries
    :return: dict - the merged dictionary
    """
    result = {}
    for dictionary in dict_args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this way I won't get the result I want. What I want is to update first dictionary from list dict2 to first four dictionaries in list dict1, then second dictionary from list dict2, to 4-8 dictionaries in list dict1 and so on.